# Java: Como cambiar imágenes que se generan por un Hilo dentro de un Canvas

Tags: java, hilos, canvas, interfaz-gráfica

Para la finalizacion de mi proyecto requiero cambiar unas imágenes que son generadas por un hilo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las bolas rojas que se lanzan desde los tanques son las que requiero cambiar por imágenes reales así como esta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El siguiente es el codigo con el cual estoy generando el hilo

```
public class HiloBala implements Runnable {


    ControladorBala controladorBala;
    Tanque bala;
    JPanel panel;

    public HiloBala(ControladorBala controladorBala, 
            Tanque tanque, JPanel panel) {
        this.controladorBala = controladorBala;
        this.controladorBala.AddBala(tanque);
        this.bala = tanque;
        this.panel = panel;

    } 


    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            this.controladorBala.moverArriba(bala);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(9);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

El siguiente es el codigo del controlador que maneja las bolas rojas

```
public class ControladorBala {

    List<Tanque> balas;
    JPanel panel;

    public ControladorBala(JPanel panel){
        balas = new ArrayList<>();
        this.panel=panel;
    }

    public void AddBala(Tanque bala){
        balas.add(bala);
    }


   public void moverAbajo(JPanel panel,Tanque bola){
        if(bola.getPosy()< panel.getHeight()-30){
            bola.setPosy(bola.getPosy()+5);
            setBala(bola);
        }
    }

    public void moverArriba(Tanque tanque){
        if(tanque.getPosy()>=5){
            tanque.setPosy(tanque.getPosy()-5);
            setBala(tanque);
        }
    }

   void setBala(Tanque bala){
       for (int i=0;i<balas.size();i++) {
           if(balas.get(i).objectId==bala.objectId){
               balas.set(i, bala);
           }
       }
   }

   public void dibujarBala(Graphics gui){
        gui.setColor(Color.RED);
        for (Tanque bala : balas) {
        gui.fillOval(bala.getPosx(), bala.getPosy(),10,10); 
       }

    }
}
```

Y este es el codigo con el que estoy creando mi Canvas

```
public class CanvasDibujable extends JPanel implements Runnable {

private ControladorTank controladorBola;
private BufferedImage fondo;
ControladorBala controladorBala;

public CanvasDibujable() {
    super();
    controladorBola = new ControladorTank();
    try {
        this.fondo = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Sebastian\\Dropbox\\EAM Ingenieria de Software\\Sistemas Distribuidos\\JuegoBaseSocketTCPPoolHilos\\JuegoBaseSocketTCPPoolHilos\\src\\recursos\\fondoPasto.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Controlar la excepcion si la imagen no se encuentra o no se pudo cargar
    }
    controladorBala = new ControladorBala(this);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        this.repaint();
    }
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(fondo, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    super.paint(graphics);
    getControladorTanque().dibujarTanque1(graphics,
            getControladorTanque().getTanque1());
    getControladorTanque().dibujarTanque2(graphics,
            getControladorTanque().getTanque2());
    controladorBala.dibujarBala(graphics);
}

/**
 * @return the controladorBola
 */
public ControladorTank getControladorTanque() {
    return controladorBola;
}

/**
 * @param controladorBola the controladorBola to set
 */
public void setControladorBola(ControladorTank controladorBola) {
    this.controladorBola = controladorBola;
}

public ControladorBala getControladorBala() {
    return controladorBala;
}

public void setControladorBala(ControladorBala controladorBala) {
    this.controladorBala = controladorBala;
}
```

}

Eso es lo que intentando hacer para dibujar mi imagen en el controlador bala modifique el metodo `dibujarBala` por lo siguiente

```
public void dibujarBala(Graphics gui){
        //gui.setColor(Color.RED);
        for (Tanque bala : balas) {
        gui.drawImage(bala.getImageBala(), bala.getPosx(), bala.getPosy(),10,10); 
       }

    }
```

Dentro de la clase tanque estoy agregando el `BufferedImage`

```
public class Tanque {

    private BufferedImage imagenTanque1;
    private BufferedImage imagenTanque2;
    private BufferedImage imagenBala;
    private int ancho;
    private int alto;
    private int posx;
    private int posy;
    private static int counter = 0;
    public final int objectId;

    public Tanque(int ancho, int alto, int x, int y){
        this.ancho=ancho;
        this.alto=alto;
        this.posx=x;
        this.posy=y;
        this.objectId = counter++;
        try {
            // A modo de ejemplo, puse la imagen en el C:, sin embargo podrías agregarla a tu proyecto, o buscarla en otro directorio
            this.imagenTanque1 = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Sebastian\\Dropbox\\EAM Ingenieria de Software\\Sistemas Distribuidos\\JuegoBaseSocketTCPPoolHilos\\JuegoBaseSocketTCPPoolHilos\\src\\recursos\\TankArriba.png"));
            this.imagenTanque2 = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Sebastian\\Dropbox\\EAM Ingenieria de Software\\Sistemas Distribuidos\\JuegoBaseSocketTCPPoolHilos\\JuegoBaseSocketTCPPoolHilos\\src\\recursos\\TankAbajo.png"));
            this.imagenBala = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Sebastian\\Dropbox\\EAM Ingenieria de Software\\Sistemas Distribuidos\\JuegoBaseSocketTCPPoolHilos\\JuegoBaseSocketTCPPoolHilos\\src\\recursos\\Bala.gif"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            this.imagenTanque1 = null;
            this.imagenTanque2 = null;
            this.imagenBala = null;
        }
    }


    public BufferedImage getImagenTanque1() {       
        return this.imagenTanque1;
    }

    public BufferedImage getImagenTanque2() {
        return this.imagenTanque2;
    }

    public BufferedImage getImageBala(){
        return this.imagenBala;
    }
    /**
     * @return the ancho
     */
    public int getAncho() {
        return ancho;
    }

    /**
     * @param ancho the ancho to set
     */
    public void setAncho(int ancho) {
        this.ancho = ancho;
    }

    /**
     * @return the alto
     */
    public int getAlto() {
        return alto;
    }

    /**
     * @param alto the alto to set
     */
    public void setAlto(int alto) {
        this.alto = alto;
    }

    /**
     * @return the posx
     */
    public int getPosx() {
        return posx;
    }

    /**
     * @param posx the posx to set
     */
    public void setPosx(int posx) {
        this.posx = posx;
    }

    /**
     * @return the posy
     */
    public int getPosy() {
        return posy;
    }

    /**
     * @param posy the posy to set
     */
    public void setPosy(int posy) {
        this.posy = posy;
    }


}
```

Error que me sale al intentar el codigo anterior

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y...¿cuál es el problema?

Comment: Estoy intentando colocar las imagen con el metodo `drawImage` pero no me funciona no se si lo estoy haciendo de una mala manera o que otra opcion me podian ayudar

Comment: Debes enseñarnos lo que has probado y porque no te funciona, ya que a primera vista la solución es muy sencilla.

Comment: Tienes tanques dibujados y tienes el pasto... una bala es más de lo mismo

Comment: Intento dibujar la imagen igual que como lo hice con el fondo de pasto y los tanque pero aun no logro cambiar las bolas rojas por imágenes me sale un error

Comment: En ese caso, eso es lo que necesitamos saber: que has intentando y que error te sale. Pulsa en [edit] y añade eso en tu pregunta.

Comment: Ya esta editada la pregunta puedes revisar

Comment: El código que has probado parece correcto. Cual es el error que obtienes?

Comment: Revisa la pregunta acabo de postear una imagen del error que me sale

Comment: Deberías revisar cómo utilizar el método antes de utilizarlo: `gui.drawImage(bala.getImageBala(), bala.getPosx(), bala.getPosy(), 10, 10, null);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error que tienes es por usar el método `drawImage` con el número incorrecto de parámetros, lo que hace que se esperen parámetros de tipos diferentes a los que pasas.

```
gui.drawImage(bala.getImageBala(), bala.getPosx(), bala.getPosy(),10,10);
```

Son 5 parámetros, que corresponden a la siguiente firma:

```
drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, Color bgcolor, ImageObserver observer)
```

Lo que puedes hacer es usar otra diferente, como estás haciendo con el fondo:

```
g.drawImage(bala.getImageBala(), bala.getPosx(), bala.getPosy(),10,10, null);
```

O buscar [en la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) otra que corresponda a lo que quieres.